# Declaring facts that are true only within the scope of a single unit test in SWI-Prolog

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, swi-prolog, plunit

As an example for this question, I have a very simple Prolog file `main.pl`, in which I've defined the colours of some shapes.

```
colour(circle, red).
colour(triangle, red).
colour(square, blue).
```

Now below that I define a predicate `same_colour/2`, which is true if both `S1` and `S2` are the same colour.

```
same_colour(S1, S2) :-
    colour(S1, C),
    colour(S2, C).
```

Testing at the top level indicates that this predicate works as expected.

```
?- same_colour(circle, triangle).
true.

?- same_colour(circle, square).
false.
```

I am trying to write unit tests using SWI-Prologs unit testing framework [plunit](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/plunit.html%27%29) for `same_colour/2`, but I want to declare facts within each individual test that are only true within the scope of that test. I've tried using the `setup` option for individual tests, as well as `asserta`, neither of which work. All of the below tests fail.

```
:- begin_tests(same_colour).

test(same_colour) :-
    colour(shape_a, colour_1),
    colour(shape_b, colour_1),
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

test(same_colour) :-
    asserta(colour(shape_a, colour_1)),
    asserta(colour(shape_b, colour_1)),
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

test(same_colour, [
    setup(colour(shape_a, colour_1)),
    setup(colour(shape_b, colour_1))
]) :-
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

:- end_tests(same_colour).
```

I've also tried:

```
test(same_colour, [
    setup(asserta(colour(shape_a, colour_1))),
    setup(asserta(colour(shape_b, colour_1))),
    cleanup(retract(colour(shape_a, colour_1))),
    cleanup(retract(colour(shape_b, colour_1)))
]) :-
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).
```

that is, first declare that `colour(shape_a, colour_1)` and `colour(shape_b, colour_1)` are facts, do the test, then 'undeclare' them. However, this test fails as well. Using `trace` it seems that `colour(shape_a, colour_1)` is never asserted (or at least is not true while my test is running.)

```
Call: (18) plunit_same_colour:'unit body'('same_colour@line 13', vars) ? creep
Call: (19) same_colour(shape_a, shape_b) ? creep
Call: (20) colour(shape_a, _G738) ? creep
Fail: (20) colour(shape_a, _G738) ? creep
Fail: (19) same_colour(shape_a, shape_b) ? creep
Fail: (18) plunit_same_colour:'unit body'('same_colour@line 13', vars) ? creep
```

I can understand now why the first two tests do not work. In the first I am testing whether `colour(shape_a, colour_1)` is true, when it hasn't been declared before, and in the second I just don't think it is correct to use `asserta` from within a predicate definition. Though it feels like something similar to my third or fourth test should be able to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

testing your tests :)

```
:- module(colour_test, [same_colour/2]).
:- use_module(library(plunit)).

colour(circle, red).
colour(triangle, red).
colour(square, blue).

same_colour(S1, S2) :-
    colour(S1, C),
    colour(S2, C).

:- begin_tests(same_colour).

test(same_colour) :-
    colour(shape_a, colour_1),
    colour(shape_b, colour_1),
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

test(same_colour) :-
    asserta(colour(shape_a, colour_1)),
    asserta(colour(shape_b, colour_1)),
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

test(same_colour, [
    setup(colour(shape_a, colour_1)),
    setup(colour(shape_b, colour_1))
]) :-
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).

:- end_tests(same_colour).
```

yields

```
1 ?- run_tests(same_colour).
% PL-Unit: same_colour 
ERROR: /home/carlo/prolog/so/colour_test.pl:14:
    test same_colour: failed

ERROR: /home/carlo/prolog/so/colour_test.pl:19:
    test same_colour: received error: asserta/1: No permission to modify static procedure `colour_test:colour/2'
Defined at /home/carlo/prolog/so/colour_test.pl:4
ERROR: goal unexpectedly failed: colour(shape_a,colour_1)
 done
% 2 tests failed
% 0 tests passed
false.
```

that is, if you want to modify the DB at runtime, let Prolog know, adding:

```
:- dynamic colour/2.
```

now it's going better:

```
2 ?- run_tests(same_colour).
% PL-Unit: same_colour 
ERROR: /home/carlo/prolog/so/colour_test.pl:16:
    test same_colour: failed

.. done
% 1 test failed
% 2 tests passed
false.
```

but the DB is 'dirty':

```
3 ?- listing(colour).
:- dynamic colour_test:colour/2.

colour_test:colour(shape_b, colour_1).
colour_test:colour(shape_a, colour_1).
colour_test:colour(circle, red).
colour_test:colour(triangle, red).
colour_test:colour(square, blue).

true.
```

Of course, it's long time known that modifying a program at runtime it's a dangerous activity... anyway, setup/cleanup are *goals*, so maybe you want

```
test(same_colour, [
    setup(( assertz(colour(shape_a, colour_1)),
            assertz(colour(shape_b, colour_1))
    )),
    cleanup(retractall(colour(_, colour_1)))
]) :-
    same_colour(shape_a, shape_b).
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a straightforward solution using in alternative Logtalk's unit test framework:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/tools/lgtunit/NOTES.md

SWi-Prolog is one of the twelve supported Prolog systems. No need for hacks with `dynamic/1` directives or for cleanup goals.

Assume, for example, that you have three sets of facts that you want to test your code with. Furthermore, assume that the code to be tested is defined in the `same_color.pl` Prolog file. Simply define a unit test object per each set of facts:

```
:- object(colors1, extends(lgtunit)).

    :- include('same_color.pl').

    colour(circle, red).
    colour(triangle, red).
    colour(square, blue).

    test(colors1) :-
        ...

:- end_object.
```

Define objects, e.g. `colors2` and `colors3` for the other sets of facts. Then:

```
| ?- logtalk_load(lgtunit(loader)).
...
| ?- logtalk_load([colors1, colors2, colors3], [hook(lgtunit)]).
...
| ?- colors1::run, colors2::run, colors3::run.
```

Or simply automate the unit tests by defining a `tester.lgt` help file and running the `logtalk_tester` automation shell script. Plenty of examples, including a sample `tester-sample.lgt` file in the Logtalk distribution. If you find it odd to use Logtalk unit testing tool to test Prolog code, know that Logtalk distribution includes a full Prolog standards conformance test suite, which provides you with further examples.